# linq join incorrect syntax error

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ query to get the rows with certain conditions. Here is the query.

```
var query = from v in dt1.AsEnumerable()
      join c in dt2.AsEnumerable() on v.Field<int>("ID") equals c.Field<int>("ID")
      where v.Field<string>("col1").Equals("abcd") 
      && (c.Field<string>("col1").Equals("8776") || c.Field<string>("col1").Equals("8775"))
      select new 
          {
             ok = (from a in v where v.Field<string>("stah").Equals("1") select a).count(),
             ok1 = (from a in v where v.Field<string>("stah").Equals("2") select a).count(),
             ok2 = (from a in v where v.Field<string>("stah").Equals("3") select a).count()

          };
```

The error is present in

```
ok = (from a in v where v.Field<string>("stah").Equals("1") select a).count()
```

The error is

> could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type
>   'system.data.DataRow'. 'Where' not found

Sample Input :
dt1

```
iD      col1      stah
1       4567        1
2       8748        2
3       3487        3
4       8776        1
```

dt2

```
iD      col1
1       4754
2       4576
```

Output

```
Get count of all rows where stah=1 && dt2.col1='4754'
```

But I cannot get it working. What is the correct syntax for this ?

Comment: It's a good habit to provide at least the error message.

Comment: `v` is a range variable here not an `IEnumerable<T>`. You can't write a LINQ like that. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get the count where `v.Field<string>("stah").Equals("1")`

Comment: Also why do you need to wrap the count in an annonymous type in the select-part?

Comment: @RahulSingh, because of this condition `where v.Field<string>("col1").Equals("abcd") && (c.Field<string>("col1").Equals("8776") || c.Field<string>("col1").Equals("8775"))`

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava - I am still confused, can you show some sample input and output you expect?

Comment: @CSharpie, because there are more conditions present there.

Comment: @RahulSingh, Update the question. Take a look

Comment: Did you use `System.Data.Linq` for datarow?

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you correctly, then this is what you need:-

```
var query = dt1.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(x => x.Field<int>("stah") == 1 
                       && dt2.AsEnumerable()
                             .Any(z => z.Field<int>("Id") == x.Field<int>("Id") 
                                      && z.Field<string>("Col1") == "4754")
                     ).Count();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need to get 3 count values. All the condition will remain same except `stah==1 or 2 or 3`. That's how I tried to wrote my query.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava - Hey you can't get them all with a single projection since they are in the same dataTable, you can wrap this inside a function and pass the `stah` dynamically. If you really wanna project them separately you will have to call `dt1.AsEnumerable()` again and again which is equivalent to calling the query altogether again.

Answer (score 1):

@HarshitShrivastava mentioned that my previous attempt at the query didn't take into account all the where conditions.

How about this version using a mix of Linq query and Linq Lambda:

```
var query = from dataRows1 in dt1.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("col1").Equals("abcd"))
               join dataRows2 in dt2.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("col1").Equals("8776") || r.Field<string>("col1").Equals("8775"))
                  on dataRows1.Field<int>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<int>("ID") into b
    select new
    {
        id = dataRows1.Field<int>("ID"),
        ok = (from a in b where a.Field<string>("stah").Equals("1") select a).Count(),
        ok1 = (from a in b where a.Field<string>("stah").Equals("2") select a).Count(),
        ok2 = (from a in b where a.Field<string>("stah").Equals("3") select a).Count()
    };
```

Note: I included the ID field in the projected output just for verifying the results. Remove as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the above way, the query `from a in dt1.AsEnumerable() where a.Field<string>("stah").Equals("1") select a).Count()` will only follow one condition & not the other conditions.